# Why can't software engineers work from home most of the time?

Tags: software-industry, work-time, telecommute, software-development, commute

I've recently quit a job that required a 2 hour+ commute (4-5 hour total). This commute was costing me a sizable portion of my monthly income. Luckily, the firm was very casual when it came to getting in late, their culture could be described as "so long as the work is done".

During a typical working day, most interaction with colleagues took the form of instant messaging, ticketing, or e-mail. Of course, I did converse face-to-face with my team frequently. The vast majority of the day was spent on solitary development. In fact, the only interaction I had with my manager was during a weekly catch-up meeting, or if something required cooperative development, or if an urgent fix was needed. If someone could not physically attend a meeting, they would usually attend via audio/video conference.

Luckily for me, the company/my manager didn't mind if I occasionally worked from home. I only worked from home if I had an urgent reason to do so (doctors appointment, etc...). I was hugely more productive at home, I maintained the communication in the same way as if I was in the office. In fact, if I had been allowed to work from home 3-4 days a week, my productivity would have, at the very least, tripled.

I understand that there's obviously some trust issues associated with working from home. The extent of which will vary from each company/manager. I can also understand why one would be required to "prove their worth" before being granted the privilege. Is the requirement to be physically at the office just tradition, or something more?

Comment: Why do you think you are so much less productive in the office?  I find it hard to believe that you can **triple** your productivity by working from home.

Comment: " Is the requirement to be physically at the office just tradition, or something more?" You are asking a question that's irrelevant to your situation. The question you should probably be asking is "how do I make a convincing argument to my boss that they should let me try working remotely?" Who, except for you, cares if the requirement to show up at the office is traditional or not?

Comment: @John Feltz - Don't second guess other people. The first firm I worked for allowed the professional staff to work from home, and we never had a problem with their productivity. Being allowed to work from home improved the morale of the staff and actually made our firm a desirable place to work. People get constantly interrupted while in the office - not so much when they work from home. And a few of them focus better on issues when they are at home. I expect the OP would be more productive if working remotely, if only because a 4-5 hour commute is exhausting, especially if the OP is driving.

Comment: There is also "face time". If you are never in the office, your colleagues may think you don't do anything.

Comment: @Brandin - One more time: I am NEVER in the office. Neither are my colleagues from across the country and overseas. You've got any more objections? Would you like to second guess the validity of our international IT consulting company's business model?

Comment: Asking for opinion is poor wording as that is out of scope.

Comment: **Security demands on-site presence**. My present assignment is at a financial institution. They are not allowed to grant access to even our development and test databases to anyone that is not on site. Anything that relates to business data may not be accessed remotely.

Comment: My main thought is those who have young children will have a hard time focusing, so it's probably best to have somewhere to go if you need to focus but otherwise if you have self-discipline and don't need other accommodations it should be fine to work from home most of the time.

Answer (score 9):

Tradition. Some managers like to see the people who work for them doing 'work'. Obviously there are some jobs where your location is important, but for software engineers, as long as the work is done, that should be all that counts.

More companies are moving to flexible arrangements, so a decent software engineer should be able to get work.

Answer (score 8):

Two thoughts.

**Not everyone works well from home**.  Some people work better with a change in scenery - the different environment in the office is a psychological cue that gets them into work mode.

**Emergency response**.  In the event that something goes really haywire, having the developers together in one place may significantly improve the response time.

Comment: And not every s/w engineer works in the way described, eg pair programming is hard if one of you is at home.

Comment: Pair programming is quite doable remotely. Just requires good tools.

Comment: "Emergency response" is nonsense. Firstly, true emergencies are rare. Secondly, there is no reason why collaboration tools that have already existed for several years don't work for it; they do.